# How to resolve class not found error in Kafka connect transform?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I need to create a kafka connector with ExtractTopic transform. As per this page https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/transforms/extracttopic.html#extracttopic, I'm doing the following steps:

```
confluent-hub install confluentinc/connect-transforms:latest

# Then plugin-path is automatically updated in /etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-distributed.properties

confluent start # This starts my confluent services including kafka-connect
```

I'm able to see following line in my connect logs:

```
cmd: confluent log connect
includes:

[2020-10-29 05:52:12,156] INFO Added plugin 'io.confluent.connect.transforms.ExtractTopic$Value' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:140)
[2020-10-29 05:52:12,156] INFO Added plugin 'io.confluent.connect.transforms.ExtractTopic$Key' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:140)
```

Now I try to create connector using following configs:

```
cat connect_config/connect-file-sink.properties 

name=file-sink
connector.class=FileStreamSink
tasks.max=1
file=/root/sink.test
topics=meetups
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
value.converter.schemas.enable=false
transforms=KeyExample
transforms.KeyExample.type=io.confluent.connect.transforms.ExtractTopic$Key
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
confluent load file-sink -d connect_config/connect-file-sink.properties

This CLI is intended for development only, not for production
https://docs.confluent.io/current/cli/index.html

{
  "error_code": 400,
  "message": "Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 2 error(s):\nInvalid value io.confluent.connect.transforms.ExtractTopic$Key for configuration transforms.KeyExample.type: Class io.confluent.connect.transforms.ExtractTopic$Key could not be found.\nInvalid value null for configuration transforms.KeyExample.type: Not a Transformation\nYou can also find the above list of errors at the endpoint `/{connectorType}/config/validate`"
}
```

Please let me know how to resolve this error.

Comment: Personally, I would suggest starting/using Connect outside of the confluent CLI. Specifically, its not clear if `/etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-distributed.properties` is actually used when starting Connect

Comment: What do you mean by outside? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Use `connect-distributed` command directly rather than `confluent start`

Comment: Okay, will try this.

Comment: Tried this, the error remains the same.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you manage to solve it @padmanabhpande?